# Why nginx/rails did not show me the full content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx

On production server I have nginx+passenger and rails 3.1.2

Somehow it can't show we full output. I have the page with ~ 150 images and links underneath. But when page loads I can see only small part of them. Is it problem in nginx config? On my local all ok (MRI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx gzip helped me, I just turned on it in nginx.conf